# Background images appear in bands in some cases

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I develop in Visual Studio. When I browse my pages, if, for example, a div has a background set using css to be an image which is, effectively, a graduated tint - it appears in bands of colour - i.e. not graduated.

Is there some setting I can change so IE shows background graduated tints properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to generate your background color. This site is a css gernerator and it generates code for IE 6-7-8-9 and other browsers.

http://www.colorzilla.com/